# Rename files to match parent folder

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, mv

I want to rename all files within a directory to match the parent folder's name.

Now I've found several results that sort of do what I want, but they all seem to rely on a static filetype, path, format, etc.

I need one that takes any crazy folder name and applies it to any files within, leaving their extension unchanged. I don't want the Parent's Parent's Parent, etc. Just something I can run in a current folder to affect all sub-folders within that folder.

For example:

Folder structure

```
This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p
|
| asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafs.mkv
|
| info.nfo
|
| proof.jpg
|
You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo
|
| video.mp4
```

Expected result

```
This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p
|
|_This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.mkv
|
|_This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.nfo
|
|_This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.jpg
|
You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo
|
| You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo.mp4
```

Could anyone advise how this can be done in a script or a single, long command?

Comment: so if you have multiple files with the same extension in the directory, then what?

Comment: What @stumblebee said. This is in general an unsafe thing to do. Two files can't have the same name, so there's a big risk that any batch command to change files to the name of the parent directory will overwrite files. I'd at least add some numbering.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as the other question asks how to *add* the directory name while this question is about *replacing* it entirely (which adds certain problems ;-)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rename` for that:

```bsh
rename -n 's/(.*)\/.*\./$1\/$1./' */*
```

This command needs to be started in the directory directly above the directories you want to process, exactly like in your example. It will first only *list* the changes for you to check, if you're happy with the results run it without `-n` to perform the renaming.

If there are multiple files with the same extension in one directory, `rename` will print a warning for every file and just leave them out. You could force overwriting with `-f`, but I highly doubt that's what you want to be done in these (rare?) cases.

#### Example run

```
$ tree
.
├── This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p
│   ├── asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfafs.mkv
│   ├── info.nfo
│   └── proof.jpg
└── You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo
    └── video.mp4
$ rename 's/(.*)\/.*\./$1\/$1./' */*
$ tree
.
├── This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p
│   ├── This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.jpg
│   ├── This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.mkv
│   └── This.Is.A.Crazy.Name.S00E00.720p.nfo
└── You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo
    └── You.See.Where.This.Is.Going.14x01.480p.crappo.mp4
```

#### Explanation

```bsh
rename 's/(.*)\/.*\./$1\/$1./' */*
```

- `s/a/b/` – `s`ubstitute `a` by `b`
- `(.*)\/.*\.` – take everything until (excl.) the last slash saving it as group 1 and take the slash and everything until (incl.) the last dot
  *and substitute it by*
- `$1\/$1.` – group 1 (dir name), a slash, group 1 again (file name) and a dot (dot before extension, which itself didn't get touched)

Comment: "-n" Excellent answer! The "*Are you sure*" crossed my mind.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did exactly what I needed.

I guess I could have clarified that this data is not in any way critical, so if something in this folder tree where to get messed up somehow, it would not be a disaster.

I appreciate your help, very much!